# Lorentzian Relativity

Tags: special-relativity

The same old questions and scenarios abound on this site about trains, ladders, twins, rockets, simultaneity, and so on.

It was acknowledged by Einstein that Lorentz's later rehashed aether-based relativity theory was neither falsified by evidence, nor inconsistent with the predictions of Einstein's own relativity theory.

In essence, Lorentz's approach with the aether explains all relativistic effects in a way that departs as little as possible from classical principles.

A crucial difference between Einstein and Lorentz is that Einstein assumes a constant one-way speed of light, whereas Lorentz does not (except in the special case of being stationary in the aether).

Both acknowledge that the two-way speed is always constant, both acknowledge that only the two-way speed is empirically measurable, and neither attempt to deny the assumption their respective theories make about the one-way speed.

JS Bell noted later that an effective way to teach relativity was first to do so in terms of acknowledging the existence of an aether and explaining relativity in broadly Lorentzian terms, and then use this as a foundation for demonstrating that Einstein's approach is equally valid but does not need to postulate an aether. In other words, following the same path Einstein took to develop the theory in the first place.

Other physics educators more recently have acknowledged the effectiveness of this approach.

I'm not however clear *how* Bell or these other educators actually teach relativity in terms of an aether - only that in general terms they claim to have done so.

My question is, are there explanations of the various thought experiments, like the train thought experiment, that attempt to take a fully Lorentzian approach? So in other words, it does not attempt to deny the aether?

Because the two theories are acknowledged (by no less than their creators) to be equal in their predictive power, it follows that it ought to be possible to explain the train thought experiment (and any other experiment) in both ways.

But I'm curious whether such an explanation is even known, and how compelling it is by comparison to the typical Einsteinian approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such explanations are not only well known but they are straightforward to construct. To construct a Lorentzian analysis there are two steps:

1. pick any inertial frame and declare that frame to be the aether frame
2. then either apply all of the standard SR formulas in that frame or use the Lorentz transform to transform to any moving frame and apply all of the standard SR formulas in that frame instead

The labeling of one frame as the aether frame is all that is required for a Lorentzian analysis. Any frame at all can be chosen and there will never be any experimental evidence to refute that choice. Or, if desired, the velocity of the aether frame can be left as an unknown which is guaranteed to cancel out of any equation for any measurement.

Comment: As an interesting side note, this is essentially how one can make the de Broglie-Bohm formulation of quantum mechanics pseudo-relativistic. The main impediment to a relativistic theory is that the momentum of one particle depends on the instantaneous positions of all of the other particles; the solution (which is rather blunt) is simply to choose a frame (or more generally a foliation of spacetime) which defines a privileged notion of simultaneity, formulate the theory in that frame, and then relate all other frames to that one via Lorentz transformations (or coordinate transformations).

Comment: The standard SR analysis cannot properly describe the Lorentzian approach, because the one-way speed isn't necessarily isotropic in the Lorentzian approach (if you are describing things in the non-stationary frame), and SR would make no mention of this. Because I've talked to you before Dale and I know your general position on things, can I suggest not pontificating so strongly on something like this where your grasp is so weak?

Comment: @J.Murray, that's an interesting point, and I gather that fathoming out the linkage between QM and Relativity was exactly why Bell was so interested in a Lorentzian approach.

Comment: @Steve the **Lorentz** transform is indeed part of **Lorentz** aether theory. The one way speed of light is indeed isotropic in all so-called “local” frames. As is easily shown through the Lorentz transform

Comment: @Dale, no, the one-way speed of light isn't isotropic in a Lorentzian approach, *except* when stationary in the aether frame. So you are already misleading the reader, and force-feeding the tenets which are in fact characteristic of the Einsteinian approach - the very approach I contrasted with the one I want to hear about: the Lorentzian approach. The fact that the one-way speed is unmeasurable experimentally, doesn't mean it doesn't need to be mentioned - it's a key part of how the two approaches work differently despite arriving at the same answers.

Comment: @Steve it is trivial to prove through the Lorentz transform that the speed of light is isotropic in the local frames in Lorentz aether theory. You seem to think that Lorentz aether theory makes its predictions through something other than the Lorentz transform. It doesn’t. It just calls the result a “local” frame

Comment: @Dale, the one-way speed of light is not directly observable, and the Lorentzian approach effectively describes how anisotropic one-way speeds are consistent with isotropic two-way speeds (which are observable and proven to be isotropic). The Einsteinian approach does not postulate anisotropic one-way speeds in the first place, because it does not postulate an aether which implies and requires that anisotropy. The speed of light is not one-way isotropic in Lorentz - not even in the "local" frame - except when the local frame is also stationary in the aether frame.